# Prove that the solution belong to ${L^2}\left( {0,T;{L^2}\left( \Omega \right)} \right)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $k \in {L^\infty }\left( {0,T} \right)$ and we assume that
$$\phi :t \mapsto u\left( t \right) + \int_0^t {k\left( s \right)u\left( s \right)ds}  \in {L^\infty }\left( {0,T;{L^2}\left( \Omega  \right)} \right).$$
Can we prove that $u \in {L^\infty }\left( {0,T;{L^2}\left( \Omega  \right)} \right)$.

My approach is here.
We have
$$\left\| {u\left( t \right)} \right\| = \left\| {\phi \left( t \right) + \int_0^t {k\left( s \right)u\left( s \right)ds} } \right\| \leqslant \left\| {\phi \left( t \right)} \right\| + \int_0^t {\left| {k\left( s \right)} \right|\left\| {u\left( s \right)} \right\|ds}  \leqslant {\left\| \phi  \right\|_{{L^\infty }\left( {0,T;{L^2}} \right)}} + {\left\| k \right\|_{{L^\infty }\left( {0,T} \right)}}\int_0^t {\left\| {u\left( s \right)} \right\|ds} .$$
Use Gronwall inequality, we get $\left\| {u\left( t \right)} \right\| \leqslant {\left\| \phi  \right\|_{{L^\infty }\left( {0,T;{L^2}} \right)}}\exp \left( {{{\left\| k \right\|}_{{L^\infty }\left( {0,T} \right)}}T} \right)$. Then we have $u \in {L^\infty }\left( {0,T;{L^2}} \right)$.

But i cant prove $u\left( t \right) \in {L^2}$.

Comment: Doesn't $\lVert u(t)\rVert \le \lVert\phi\rVert_\infty\exp(\lVert k\rVert_\infty T)$ imply in particular that $\lVert u(t)\rVert < \infty$, hence that $u(t) \in \operatorname L^2$?  Or is $\lVert u(t)\rVert$ not the $\operatorname L^2$ norm?

Comment: At first we dont have $u\left( t \right) \in {L^2}\left( \Omega  \right)$. So we cant define $\left\| {u\left( t \right)} \right\|$ and we dont have
$$\left\| {u\left( t \right)} \right\| \leqslant {\left\| \phi  \right\|_{{L^\infty }\left( {0,T;{L^2}} \right)}} + {\left\| k \right\|_{{L^\infty }\left( {0,T} \right)}}\int_0^t {\left\| {u\left( s \right)} \right\|ds} .$$

Comment: Which space does $u(t)$ belong to, to start wth? When you say that $\Phi\in L^\infty L^2$ you define the Bochner integral $\int_0^t ku$, so implicitly you must assume that $u$ belongs to some Bochner space in order to ascribe a menaing this integral.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you should first assume that $u\in L^1_{loc}L^2$ in order to make the question meaningful in the first place (in particular $u(t)$ is unambiguously defined as an $L^2(\Omega)$ for a.e. time), and only then try to upgrade the time regularity to $L^\infty$

Comment: For example, you can check by hand that, for any arbitrary point $x\in\Omega$, the distribution-valued function $u(t):=\exp(-\int _0^1 f)\delta_{x}$ solves $u'+ku=0$, hence $\phi(t)=u(t)+\int_0^t k u\equiv 0$ has all the regularity that one may think about. However of course this specific function $u$ does not belong to $L^\infty L^2$.